# Magento2 : Postman Query to update Status of SKU [To enable/Disable]

Tags: php, postman, magento2

I am trying to update status of SKU in Magento2 using SOAP API using POSTMAN tool.
It is not working. Please help me to write a right working query. Trying since a week now.

Running below query in POSTMAN tool

```
http://111.123.33.44/rest/V1/products/24-MB01?status=0
```

Below response I get in POSTMAN

```
{
    "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "product"
    }
}
```

Not able to resolve this. Help in this regards is highly appreciated!!!
Best regards,

Comment: What's your POST data?

Comment: This is PUT call. Updated Authorization with key(Bearer token) and under "Params" status = 0. It automatically creates this below link: http://111.123.33.44/rest/V1/products/24-MB01/1/?status=0